# property map is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I want to render purpose array. I am using map here but still its showing that map is undefined.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
//userWorkDetails.js

const UserAccountDetails = props => {
    const { className, userid, user, ...rest } = props;
    console.log(`purpose::::${props.purpose}`)
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [parameters, setParameters] = useState([]);
    // const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [open, setopen] = useState(false);
```

Here I am using purpose.

```
const [purpose,setPurpose]=useState(" ");
```

Here I am mapping purpose to print the elements in the array.

```
async function createPurpose(){
    let lookingFor="";
    console.log(`purpose::::::create:${props.purpose}`);
    props.purpose.map((element)=>{
        lookingFor=lookingFor+element+", ";
    });
    lookingFor=lookingFor.substring(0,lookingFor.length-1);
    setPurpose(lookingFor);
}
 
//userDetails.js
    
const UserDetail = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [isData,setIsdata] = useState(false);
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [purpose,setPurpose]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        sendHttpCall('GET', `users/user_detail/${props.match.params.userid}`, null, props).then((response) => {
        setPurpose(response.purpose);
```

Here I have made an array and I am sending response to `userWorkDetails`.

```
        let s=["WFH","Hiring","Freelance"];
        response.lookingFor=s;
        setUser(response);
              console.log( `outer:purpose:${purpose}`)
        })
    },[]);
```

Comment: Your error is actually showing that `props.purpose` is undefined. Can you check your code to see if you are setting purpose correctly? Verify `setPurpose(response.purpose)` and other places where you are using `setPurpose` calls.